# Nuget could not install package Jint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install Jint from Nuget but it fails, no matter what .Net version I sellect (I target 4.5 ideally)

```
   PM> Install-Package Jint
    Successfully installed 'Jint 2.8'.
    Successfully uninstalled 'Jint 2.8'.
    Install failed. Rolling back...
    Install-Package : Could not install package 'Jint 2.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Client', 
    but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
    At line:1 char:16
    + Install-Package <<<<  Jint
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: See, you have correctly changed the versions, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: If this is a question, yes I have

Comment: There is a Jint fork on v2.4 compatible with .Net 3.5: https://github.com/Nogrod/jint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Jint code issues](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/issues/125) it is saying that they does not support .Net 3.5, as it seems you have when you tried to install Jint. There it is suggested to create a fork from CodePrex instead of using nuget:

> Please use Jint v1 from CodePlex, or create a fork and try to do the conversion.

Comment: I've tried 4.5, 4.0, 4.0 Client profile and 2.0 as well. I managed to find Jint 2.0 I'm using at the moment. I would rather build the gidhub project, but I can't at the moment  because I have VS express at home and it don't support cross-platform projects (damn microsoft :). Anyway, those issues are strange, I imagine it will actually work with 4.0 or 4.5

Comment: @JDE it should work on 4.0 or 4.5, I don't think it's something else that you can do other than building yourself the project from github in this case.